# Does passing objects as arguments represent an associative relationship?

Tags: ruby, associative

What is the best way to enforce an associative relationship between these two classes?

```
class ExcelFile
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end



class Commodity

    attr_accessor(
    :xau
    )

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end


    class PriceSeries
        def initialize(source, name)
            @source = source
            @name = name
        end
    end
end
```

So to instantiate the classes:

```
mm8_prices = ExcelFile.new("some_exlsx_file")
gold = Commodity.new("gold")
gold.xau = Commodity::PriceSeries.new(mm8_prices, "gold")
```

The way I'm enforcing the relationship is by passing instances as parameters. This feels clunky to me, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create all three together, perhaps something like this:

```
class Commodity
  def self.create(commodity_name, excel_name)
    c = Commodity.new(commodity_name)
    e = ExcelFile.new(excel_name)
    c.xau = Commodity::PriceSeries.new(e, commodity_name)
    return c, e
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
commodity, excel = Commodity.create("gold", "example.xls")
```

The `create` method is a typical class method:

- There is nothing special about the method or its name.
- The method is not defined in any typical superclass.
- Some developers like to name this kind of method `make` or `factory` or `init`.
- It is totally unrelated to a Rails app controller `create` method.

This kind of creation is sometimes called a "factory" design pattern. The pattern is analogous to a factory that creates a fully-built product with a bunch of parts.

To coordinate the models in an ongoing way, consider a "conductor" design pattern a.k.a. "mediator" design pattern. The pattern is analogous to a symphony conductor who coordinates the various musicians, or a go-between manager person who helps people work with each other.

The code above is just a suggestion to point you in the right direction; you'll write your code for your particular needs, for example if you want more than one price series per commodity, or a commodity name different than the price series name, etc.

If you want a bunch of choices, you can use an options hash by writing something like this:

```
def self.create(options={})
  c = e = nil  # it's good practice to initialize these
  if options[:commodity_name]
    c = Commodity.new(options[:commodity_name])
  end
  if options[:excel_name]
    e = ExcelFile.new(options[:excel_name])
  end
  ...
  return c, e
end
```

Usage:

```
c, e = Commodity.create(commodity_name: "gold", excel_name: "my.xls")
```

You can make options optional, or varied, or write business logic in your `create` method that provides default options, or validations, etc.

There are ways to streamline this kind of creation, if you have many options, or want to do this with many classes.

For more on design patterns, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

Comment: Thanks, I've been meaning to find a book on design patterns. What is this code actually doing? I have never seen the create method before and it doesn't seem to work when instantiating classes in place of x = Class.new(param)

Comment: In this case though a price series can't exist without a commodity, but a commodity may have zero or several price series'